# How do I remove parts of a cirlce?

Tags: adobe-illustrator

[image]

Hi there. I really want to remove the parts of these circles marked by the yellow circles, but I've had a lot of difficulty doing so. Can anyone help.

Answer (score 6):

- Select all
- Grab the **Shape Builder Tool**
- Click-drag across the pieces you want to join together.

Note: Holding down the <kbd>Option/Alt</kbd> key with the Shape Builder Tool will *delete* sections.

It's actually a very quick thing to make interlocking rings with the **Shape Builder Tool**. Just a lot of click-dragging.

[image]

Comment: Show off with your fancy gifs! Nice work